# Was the living room called the "death room" around World War I? If so, by whom?

Tags: household, etymology

On a Reddit post I recently stumbled across the surprising assertion that the living room was once called the death room, with the explanation being given variously that it's where you would mourn the dead, or it's where you would leave their bodies during times of great death until someone could come along and pick it up.

I looked on Wikipedia and discovered the claim repeated there, with [a random blog](https://www.builddirect.com/blog/the-fascinating-history-of-the-living-room/) given as the citation:

> **The death room**
>
> Influenza was rampant after World War 1 and many people lost their lives. Not having the means to bury bodies immediately, and wishing to take the time to mourn, bodies were often stacked in an unused part of the house – typically the Parlor, as most people were not entertaining during these horrible times.
>
> **Introducing the living room**
>
> When things started looking brighter after the influenza outbreak subsided it began to feel morbid to call this area the death room. Ladies Home Journal – THE magazine of that time – said that with the inevitable return to the socialization and happiness of the days before the outbreak, the death room should be ‘livened’ up and therefore the term living room came to be.

This really, really sets off my bullshit detector, and after a quick Google the only things I can find repeating the claim are random blogs. But I'm really not sure how to verify it — it seems like the sort of thing that *could* be true, but probably isn't.

Further evidence hinting towards the falseness of this claim is the OED entry for "living-room" (incidentally there is no entry for "death-room"), which while light on the etymology, lists a number of 19th century examples of "living-room" starting from 1825, including some clearly used to refer to a specific room. While this doesn't completely rule out the term "death room" as having existed, it certainly rules out the idea that the term "living-room" was invented in the 1910s, and so casts yet more doubt on the whole story.

> 1825 Greenhouse Comp. I. 9 No living-room should depend for its ventilation on such of its windows as may communicate with a green-house.
>
> 1857 C. Vaux Villas & Cottages 119 Under the living-room is a basement-kitchen.

If it really is true, I'm curious as to where in the world this happened (Britain? America? Specific parts thereof?), for how long it was the case (just during the war or for a significant time before it?),  and anything else about the specific cases in which one might have had a "death room".

Comment: Apparently, „Ladies Home Journal“ was a magazine in the United States of America.

Comment: In the United States, about 292,000 flu deaths were reported between September–December 1918, which was about 1/350 of the population. It is hard to see how bodies would be "stacked up in parlours", unless they were funeral parlours, where there would be nothing unusual about having dead bodies.

Comment: Many sources, e.g. https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1995/08/12/the-slow-death-of-the-american-living-room/e1cfbaae-3bee-460e-80aa-1121221ca5a3/, date the alleged LHJ article to 1910, *before* either WWI or the influenza pandemic.  If so it may be possible to find the article online or in a library.  The linked Washington Post article says architectural historians think this is "apocryphal", but it's not clear whether they suspect the article never existed, or that it did exist but that the phrase "living room" was already established.

Comment: [HathiTrust](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015011414193&view=1up&seq=63) has what appears to be all the 1910 issues of LHJ.

Comment: On [page 37 of the October 1, 1910 issue of LHJ](https://hdl.handle.net/2027/mdp.39015011414193?urlappend=%3Bseq=930) (page 931 of the scan), there's an article "For the Bride Who Does Her Own Work" describing several house floor plans including "living-rooms".  They don't suggest the term is one they just made up, so I think we can assume it was already common. It doesn't answer the claim about "death room" but it does at least show that "living room" wasn't introduced postwar as a replacement.

Comment: If anyone has access to the full Oxford English Dictionary (in print or online) their etymology and quotations for "living room" would probably be good evidence here. They'd probably also have an entry marked "archaic" for "death room" if the story is true.

Comment: @IMSoP I actually do, never even thought of looking there. One moment...

Comment: @IMSoP No entry in the OED for "deathroom", "death-room", or "death room". There is one for "living-room" and the earliest citation given in my (out of date) edition is "1825 Greenhouse Comp. I. 9 No living-room should depend for its ventilation on such of its windows as may communicate with a green-house.". No mention of "death" in the living-room entry either but not much etymological info is present there, just citations.

Comment: Could you upgrade the qeustion to include OED and ["Cambridge etym: 1795"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/living%20room#etymonline_v_30798), and it's not just random blogs, but for notorious notability even the [cesspool of disinfo: WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_room)?

Comment: @IMSoP Maybe, yep. I thought they were a nice addition for "reasons for doubt" and would also preclude some lazier types of answers…

Comment: There is also reference in Wikipedia to one [Edward Bok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Bok) coining the term. Since he was born in 1863 and the OED has a citation from 1825, we can reasonably conclude that this is false - although it might be a lead on where the myth about "death room" came from.

Comment: @LangLаngС updated the question to include the OED findings. I already mentioned the Wikipedia page in the question, indeed it's where I found the random blog citation. Have I misunderstood what you were suggesting there?

Comment: This would seem strange to call it a death room for something that doesn't happen that often. Even if it was true about storing dead bodies there I would think it was more often used for other things as there wasn't enough room in a house to dedicate it just to that.

Comment: @NateEldredge yep, which is why I included the 1857 citation when I edited the question, which very clearly refers to a specific room :)

Comment: @JoeW: Well, I understand that a [parlour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parlour) was typically used only for very formal occasions.  It wasn't literally *only* for deaths but that was one of the relatively few times it would be used.  I think it was a form of conspicuous consumption, that you could afford to have a room that you used so rarely.

Comment: @Muzer: Thanks, didn't see that edit at first.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't think having a parlor was common for many people and the wiki link you provided even mentions that it was for people of status. Because of this I don't think it is a fair comparison to what is now known as the living room as they both serve different purposes and how often they are designed to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1990 book [Sleeping Beauty:
Memorial Photography in America](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sleeping_Beauty/wS7XAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22funerals%20were%20being%20performed%20in%20Funeral%22) says:

> To remove the stigma of death from the home this "death room" became a "living room" by simple decree by the editor of the *Ladies Home Journal*. By the end of the first decade of the twentieth century more and more funerals were being performed in Funeral "Parlors." And the home no longer had a "parlor." The "living room" became a true room for the living.

...

> Edward Bok , editor of the Ladies Home Journal , stipulates that room designs for the Journal never show parlors , but rather “ living rooms".

The 1921 book [A Dutch Boy Fifty Years After](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Dutch_Boy_Fifty_Years_After/ypwUAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) by Edward Bok says at page 136:

> and in place of the American parlor , which he considered a useless room , should be substituted either a living - room or a library .

The closest I see in the actual *Ladies Home Journal* is [September 1887](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/Ladies%27_Home_Journal_and_Practical_Housekeeper_Vol.4_No.10_%28September%2C_1887%29.pdf):

> A really handsome, tasteful parlor - and not a grand apartment by any means, but one that might better, perhaps, be called a "living-room" —is a far rarer sight than a pretty bedroom ; and when not much used, it is too often all piano and carpet. It is to be supposed that there are a few other things in the room; but the piano as large and the carpet loud, and attention is therefore riveted upon them. With dead-white walls for a background, a more unhappy combination could not well be inspired. And all this ugliness, when charming rooms can be had under the most adverse circumstances.

However, the point of Bok in his book is that his house plans would avoid having a "parlor" and instead have a "living room".

So the term "death room" was not used as the permanent name for the room, the issue is between "parlor" and "living room" and Ladies Home Journal avoided "parlors" in favor of "living rooms" prior to the time frame mentioned in the blog.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but you should make it clear that "death room" was not the actual name, and add that this had nothing to do with influenza -- it was simply common before the 20th century to mourn over a body at home, as it still is in many parts of the world.

Comment: Currently, I do not see how this answers the question about any "death room". The whole Bok-angle is full of overstatement at its core. Where should the "stigma" come from? However, Burns is a source to dig deeper into, as well as Laderman ("RIP"). Hint: it is not about storing ("stack"!, surplus?) dead, but wake, display & viewing; in short: long established cultural norms, not really connected to flu, but death in general & in families, public/private ritual and changing attitudes.

Comment: Among other aspects: "Death room" was a temporary function for rooms called the salon, the parlor, in a private home, until "funeral parlors" became more common. Parlor in a home that had them being often unused for everyday living, but kept closed for more special occasions, gatherings, meetings (the heating!) a semi-public space of the house. This emphasises *before* 1920s, for many decades as the timeframe to look at for such 'nicknames'? Hop to the HubofR  But then your now last para is in need of more direct refs?

Comment: @LangLаngС "death room" meant the room where someone died.  As in "It may be difficult to absolutely disinfect a death-room in a private residence by the use of formaldehyde, but the room is certainly made much safer than it would have been without such fumigation" https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Medical_Age/vSygAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Death+room%22&pg=PA619&printsec=frontcover

Comment: That is true & incomplete, as sometimes people were transported into a more spacious accommodation, so that more people could gather to say good bye, to the still living but going – thus in the parlor, where they were expected to die and then be on view… Or would you understand that as Bok, blogs or WP seeing the parlor as were most people suddenly drop dead?

Comment: @LangLаngС the tradition was "the body was moved to the parlor where it was put on view" https://www.google.com/books/edition/Up_the_Mainstream/PZIlAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22body+was+moved+to+the+parlor%22&dq=%22body+was+moved+to+the+parlor%22&printsec=frontcover I don't think people dying in the parlor was typical.

Comment: The claim that Edward Bok created the term "living room" seems to be false: Wikipedia lists his birth as 1863, but the OED apparently has citations from 1825 and 1857. As such, it's not really clear how he fits into this story: did he make a comment about the "death room" while popularising an existing term? Was that existing term coined by someone else in contrast to "death room"?

Comment: @IMSoP I have access to the subscription OED, and the 1824/1825 example is "living-room" in contrast to a greenhouse where people don't live.  The place where people live should not depend upon the greenhouse for ventilation.  Then the next entry is 1867, not 1857.

Comment: @IMSoP The 1989 OED had the supposed 1857 example, but it has since been deleted. (completely deleted, not just re-dated).

Comment: @DavePhD That's interesting. 1867 is still far too early to attribute to Edward Bok, though, since [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Bok) he was 4 years old at the time (and living in the Netherlands). If he's supposed to have coined it while editor of the Ladies Home Journal, any example prior to 1889 is evidence against.

Comment: @IMSoP A better example than the OED quotes is this 1850 reference https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Model_Houses_for_Families_Built_in_C/ve9fAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22living+room%22&pg=PT17&printsec=frontcover which uses the term "living-room" numerous times including in many floor plans.  Bok definitely didn't coin the term.  His contribution was just to emphasize living rooms over parlors.